# Install Helm on Virtual Box

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have three VMs in Virtual box, each of those have 2 interfaces:

- enp0s3 is going into internet;
- enp0s8 is the communication between VMs.

I have initiated Kubernetes by forcing the Kubernetes nodes communication on the enp0s8 interface with `--apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.100` argument because by default it was taking the enp0s3 interface and Kubernetes cluster works fine.

I would like to install Helm in the same manner: forcing to communicate on the enp0s8 interface. If I am doing just `helm init` and then `helm init --upgrade` I am getting that it tries to connect to Tiller on the enp0s3, not on the enp0s8:

```
george@kubernetes-master:~$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.5", GitCommit:"89bd14c1541fa93a09492010030fd3699ca65a97", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.2.102:10250: connect: no route to host
```

I have tried several arguments of `helm init`, but I couldn't find the successful one to initiate helm on the second interface. 
Any idea how can be done and if is possible?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to install Helm3 with no errors, but the IP of the pod I am getting still from the first interface instead of the second one:

```
dante@kube-master:~$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
my-release-nginx-ingress-57467494b4-z2g2w   1/1     Running   0          53s   10.244.2.2   kube-worker2   <none>           <none>
```

I've deployed the nginx Helm chart with the following commands:

```
dante@kube-master:~/.kube$ kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.56.100:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

```
dante@kube-master:~/.kube$ helm install my-ingress-controller nginx/nginx-ingress --kubeconfig /home/dante/.kube/config
NAME: my-ingress-controller
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Apr 29 18:48:52 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
The NGINX Ingress Controller has been installed.
```

Any idea how I can deploy the pod on the second interface with Helm?

Thanks,
George

Comment: You should fix 'kubectl cluster-info' first, then go with helm. Check 'kubectl config view' and maybe adjust it to point to correct IP. It looks like Helm doesn't allow to bind to outgoing IP.

Comment: You should also use helm v3 instead of v2.

Comment: @AlexVorona: Thanks for your reply. Both commands mention that the cluster runs on the second interface. I have updated the question. If you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: @FL3SH: Thanks for your indication. Helm3 it doesn't have Tiller and I pass this problem, but I still get an IP for the pod from the first interface, not second one. I have updated the question with an update. If you have any idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate where problem may be execute following command:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
```

Execute  `$ kubectl config view` - adjust it to point to proper IP. It looks like Helm doesn't allow to bind to outgoing IP.

Then check firewall status:

```
$ systemctl status firewalld
```

Run below commands to stop and disable firewall:

```
$ systemctl stop firewalld  
$ systemctl disable firewalld
```

**Advice**: use newest version of [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/)- upgrade helm to **v3.1.0**.  There is special plugin to do this - [helm-2to3](https://github.com/helm/helm-2to3).
To upgrade helm follow steps in this documentation: [helmv2-v3](https://helm.sh/blog/migrate-from-helm-v2-to-helm-v3/).
See changes in newest version of helm: [helm-v3](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/v2_v3_migration/).

Please take a look: [helm-kubernetes](https://medium.com/@anthonyganga/getting-started-with-helm-tiller-in-kubernetes-part-one-3250aa99c6ac).

Similar problem: [conection-issue-helm](https://chengdol.github.io/2019/08/19/k8s-no-route-to-host/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did installed Helm3, but I still do not get the pod on the second interface. I have updated the question with an update. If you have any idea, please let me know.